# When i click on a option how to make that option as selected in JQUery?

Tags: jquery

HI,
 i am having a select dropdown like

```
   <select id="listForms">
    <option value="Personal Form" id="25">Personal Form</option>
    <option value="Employee Details Form" id="24">Employee Details Form</option>
    <option value="Contact Form" id="45">Contact Form</option>


     </select>
```

When i click on a option how to make that option as selected in JQUery??

Edit :

i have tried it with

```
     $("#listForms option").click(function (){
      $("#listForms option").attr("selected",true); but not working

     });
```

also how to find which one has been selected later?? in JQuery ?? please suggest me..

Comment: Isn't it the default behavior?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want jquery to select the option for you? Do you want jquery to tell you which is the selected option??

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#listForms option:selected");
```

will get the selected option.

Answer (score 1):

With the following HTML

```
<select id="listForms">
    <option value="Personal Form" id="25">Personal Form</option>
    <option value="Employee Details Form" id="24">Employee Details Form</option>
    <option value="Contact Form" id="45">Contact Form</option>
</select>
```

The following jQuery would tell pop up an alert box with the value you've specified:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select#listForms").change(function() {
         alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

For example, when you click "Personal Form", you'd see an alert window that says "Personal Form".

You could change `$(this).val()` to `$(this).attr('id')` if you wanted "25" to pop up when you choose the "Personal Form" option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need: http://jgeewax.wordpress.com/2008/09/01/jquery-dropdown-fun/

EDIT - with props to the site mentioned above:

This is the final solution he gives:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select.links").change(function() {
             window.location = $(this).val();
        });
    });
</script>
```

With this html snippet:

```
<select class="links">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">—</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: will u please post the thing in that page here .. i am not able to open that site.. Blocked

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want the vaule and id from the options?... try this:

```
<select id="listForms">
 <option value="">Select a Form</option>
 <option value="Personal Form" id="25">Personal Form</option>
 <option value="Employee Details Form" id="24">Employee Details Form</option>
 <option value="Contact Form" id="45">Contact Form</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#listForms").change(function() {
  alert( "Selected Option: id = " + $(this).find('option:selected').attr("id") + ", " + $(this).val() );
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my snippet code here The problem i have is after i select an option and the pages url changes and appends a value to the URL the value i selected isn't set to what i selected but goes back to "select" the default value.

```
<select id="Phones">

    <option value="Select">select</option>
    <option value="Alcatel">Alcatel</option>
    <option value="BlackBerry">BlackBerry</option>
    <option value="HTC">HTC</option>
    <option value="Huawei">Huawei</option>
    <option value="LG">LG</option>
    <option value="Motorola">Motorola</option>
    <option value="Nokia">Nokia</option>
    <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option value="Sony">Sony</option>
</select>


// Set the onchange event for the new dropdown
$("#Phones").change(function() { checkSelected(); });

// Run the onchange event to perform any default actions necessary
checkSelected();

function checkSelected() {
    // You could use the value of the dropdown in another SPServices request
    // here or just perform some other code



     var m = $('#Phones').find("option:selected").val();
     if (m !== 'Select')
     {

     var url = "/m.aspx?m=" + m;
     window.location = url;
     alert(m);



    }


}
```